# difference between document.cookie and res.cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

When making cookies in the client computer,

All I know was res.cookie

for example (in nodejs-express),

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.cookie('count', 1);
    res.send('something');
}
```

but I found that I can also make cookies with using document.cookie.

So what is the major difference between those two when making cookies?

(likewise when reading cookies, req.cookies vs document.cookie)

Is document.cookie more bigger concept than res.cookies or req.cookies? 
without need of any req, res parameter, so whenever want to make cookies then I can just using document.cookie?

I`ve already read the articles of w3school about what the document.cookies, req.cookies, res.cookies. but cannot figure out the differences existing between those.

thanks.

Comment: The provided snippet looks like ``Express.js``, am I right?

Comment: yep thats right..... ah..... I realized... is that res.cookie only available for express..!?

Comment: ah... I was fool

Comment: thanks @Pedram marandi give me an answer and i`ll adopt you

Comment: That's fine mate, btw I've written a full answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of `Express.js`, the Node server does not have access to the `document` object. So usually with the `cookie-parser` middleware, we are able to access the request cookies.

Based on the Express.js documentation,

**res.cookie(name, value [, options]):**

> Sets cookie name to value. The value parameter may be a string or
>   object converted to JSON.

**req.cookies:**

> When using cookie-parser middleware, this property is an object that
>   contains cookies sent by the request. If the request contains no
>   cookies, it defaults to {}.