# Res.cookie vs document.cookie, is there any advantage between them for security?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, express, cookies

I wanted to set a cookie to save data of the signed in members, however, I got confused by two choices.

`res.cookie` by using Express framework which I think sets/reads the cookie in server-side.

`document.cookies` by using Javascript in client-side I guess.

I read this post:

[difference between document.cookie and res.cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353602/difference-between-document-cookie-and-res-cookie)

But I still don't know what the actual different and advantage between them, is there any different for setting/reading cookies in server-side than in client-side or vice-versa? Is one more secure than the other?

I read articles and stuff about `document.cookies` and little about `res.cookie` but no one of them talks about the security or at least the difference between the two.

Comment: My personal opinion that there is no security risk difference. I may be wrong though. I think it boils down to what works best for you. If you need to immediately set a cookie, then do it server side. If you have a heavy javascript application and the user does X action and requires the creation of a cookie, then use document.cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `res.cookie` by using Express framework which I think sets/reads the cookie in server-side.

No, cookies are inherently a client-side thing (held on the client, sent to the server with requests, updated by the server when necessary in responses).

`res.cookie` is used in server-side code to send a cookie to the client to be held on the client. `document.cookie` is available in client-side code to see and manipulate cookies for the page's origin.

From [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie):

> All `res.cookie()` does is set the HTTP `Set-Cookie` header with the options provided. Any option not specified defaults to the value stated in RFC 6265.